# R-3.2.2-win.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install R on my win 7 32 bit machine. Every time I try I get the error "R-3.2.2-win.exe is not a valid win32 application".
Can somebody please help me with what the problem is and how to resolve it?

I found a solution at [github](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/issues/35) but I don't know how to set the command "setInternet2(TRUE)".

Comment: Your antivirus is corrupting the download.

Comment: By my antivirus (bitdefender in this case) did not gave any warning or message about repairing or the file being corrupt.

Comment: Have you tried to download the installer again ? Maybe the installer file got corrupted during the transfer...

Comment: I've tried installing V 3.1 and 3.2 every time I got the same error.

Comment: Try to check if the downloaded exe is corrupted by computing the md5 hash of R-3.2.2-win.exe ([there are some utilities for win](http://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7)) , and check if correspond to the one specified [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/md5sum.txt). If the file it's ok, you probably have something wrong in your OS (e.g. some system dll missing or something like that) ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am downloading the setup from the mirror and will check again.

Comment: Download the file from an [https mirror](https://cran.rstudio.com/) if you want to make sure it doesn't get tampered with.